# Formatting output java

Tags: java, format, output

I'm trying to get my output look a little better. As long as I keep it very simple (as shown below) it works fine, but when I put the information in an ArrayList and use a constructor, I get stuck.

```
public class printing2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.format("%-10s%-15s%-15s",
            "LastName", "FirstName", "SocialNo");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.format("%-10s%-15s%-15s",
            "James", "Johnson", "12345678");        
    }
}
```

I have tried to Google this for some time now, and I have tried about a thousand different ways to solve this but I just can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Please share the code with issue

Comment: What output you're expecting?

Comment: If you want to see it like a table, you should use \t, but it is not clear what you want to do...

Comment: If you don't show us the code that isn't working, how are we supposed to be able to tell what you're doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

JJ72,
You were close.  This may be what you were looking for:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<testPrint> list = new ArrayList<>();

        testPrint p1 = new testPrint("James", "Johnson", "12345678");

        list.add(p1);

        System.out.println(String.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s", "FirstName", "LastName", "SocNumber"));
        for (testPrint l : list) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s", l.getFname(), l.getLname(), l.getnumber()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AAhhhh. Yes! Thank you very much. I will have to put the format "inside" the println-statement and get. the variables I want to be printed out. Awsome :)